# 'Handshake Failed' error using Retrofit in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gson, retrofit

How can I fix this error?

txt.text=t.Messag ====> Handshake Failed

my main activity

```
 `fun getMyData(){
     val Base_URL="https://tgju.amirhossein.info/"
     val retrofitBuilder= Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(Base_URL)
            .build()
            .create(API::class.java)
     val retrofitData=retrofitBuilder.getData()
     retrofitData.enqueue(object: Callback<List<MyDataItem>?>{
     override fun onResponse(
             call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>,
             response: Response<List<MyDataItem>?>
              ) {
                  val responseBody=response.body()!!
                  if (response.isSuccessful) {
                  val txt=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt)
                  txt.text= responseBody[0].key
                }
      }
      override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>, t: Throwable) {
              val txt=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt)
              txt.text=t.Message
      }

  } )}`
```

...............................

Interface

`interface API { @GET("api/price/currency") fun getData(): Call<List<MyDataItem>>}`

..............................

Data Item Class

`data class MyDataItem( val key: String, val price: String, val title: String )`

...............................

Data Server

`[ { "key": "price_dollar_rl", "price": "492,330", "title": "\u062f\u0644\u0627\u0631" }, { "key": "price_eur", "price": "538,800", "title": "\u06cc\u0648\u0631\u0648" } ]`

...............................

Link:

`https://tgju.amirhossein.info/api/price/currency`

Answer (score 0):

Just access the `https://tgju.amirhossein.info/` via browser and you will see a message `Invalid SSL certificate` from cloudfare. The issue is not about retrofit and kotlin - it is about the fact, that your site is using invalid certificate so the handshake fails, because the client does not trust the server.